# Get next cell in UIcollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, indexpath

I need to get the next cell inside cellForItem within a collection view so that I can update a view object. When I try the following below it doesn't work. I've also tried `indexPathForVisibleItems` passing in `indexPath.row + 1` and the produces an index out of range error.

```
    let index = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: indexPath.section)
            if let nextCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: index) as! MKRCell {
                nextCell.setupWaitView(time: timeToWait)
                nextCell.waitViewHeightConstraint.constant = 80
                nextCell.waitView.alpha = 1
                nextCell.waitView.isHidden = false
            }
```

Is this possible to achieve or will I need to do this via another way?

Thanks

Comment: Its much better to change data and use that data to create cells.

Comment: At the moment cellForItem was called, the next cell isn't available. So why you want to do that? Can you explain more details?

Comment: Trying to call a method on the next cell if the current cell has a specific value (timeToWait).

Comment: I think you should save the timeToWait value without cell. Then in `cellForItem` you just set it value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No,** it is not possible to get the cell object before initialization in `cellForItemAt` but here
you can receive the call before displaying the cell from `UICollectionViewDelegate`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if let myCell = cell as? MKRCell {

     }
}
```

**AND**

If you want to set up the cell you have to setup view in the `UICollectionViewDataSource`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

}
```

Comment: Trying willDisplay, having trouble casting the nextCell as! MKRCell though!

Comment: This already nextCell do not apply any calculation only type cast it to your call class

Comment: I need to access the nextcell as MKRCell so that can call a method from within it.

Answer (score 1):

You should update the cell in:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

Remember to modify only the cell you'll be returning from this method. Other cells might not have exist at that moment.

Alternatively you can keep a weak reference to the cell and update it when needed.

Comment: I did try the above inside cellForItem but it didn't work, including reloading the item at the specific index + 1